# Symfony 4.1: doctrine:fixtures:load not reading test configuration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to override my DBAL Driver class in order to work around [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/pull/127) and be able to truncate my database.
I followed [this guide](https://coderwall.com/p/staybw/workaround-for-1701-cannot-truncate-a-table-referenced-in-a-foreign-key-constraint-using-doctrine-fixtures-load-purge-with-truncate), but my custom Driver is never used.
Is it normal that the command:

`bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test --purge-with-truncate -n`

Does not load the configuration file?

By the way, this is how my config file looks like (config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml):

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        #driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        #server_version: '5.6'
        driver_class: App\DBAL\Driver
        url: '%env(resolve:TEST_DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Comment: what does `php bin/console debug:config doctrine` gives you as output

Comment: @zizoujab `bin/console debug:config doctrine --env=test`:

_The service "security.firewall.map" has a dependency on a non-existent service ".security.request_matcher.ZAICcXS"._

(I never had this error anywhere else)